# Дополнить придатком изменений — можно так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, плеоназм

Можно ли написать "**Дополнить игру небольшим придатком изменений**"? Или это будет речевая ошибка, ведь слово "придаток" уже означает "дополнение"?

Comment: Ну да типа тавтологии что-то. Но вообще тут слова как-то не вяжутся друг с другом, а придаток так вообще без словаря не разберешься что это. Лучше всего: "Дополнил игру небольшим модом." Уже даже "дополнил игру небольшой модификацией" звучит коряво.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, стилистически предложение некорректно.Нельзя дополнить игру дополнением, модификацией.

Можно написать так: Внесли (небольшие) дополнения и изменения (модификации) в игру, дополнили игру...

К тому же "придаток" имеет немного другое значение и в этом контексте не вяжется.

ПРИДАТОК, -тка; м. 1. Дополнение к чему-л., **не имеющее самостоятельного значения. Ненужный п. Существовать в виде придатка.** 2. **Спец. Название некоторых образований в живом организме. П. мозга. П. яичника. Придатки кожи (сальные и потовые железы, ногти, волосы). <Придаточный, -ая, -ое (2 зн.). П-ые образования у водорослей. П-ые железы. П. желудок у птиц.** ◊ Придаточное предложение. Лингв. Часть сложноподчинённого предложения, синтаксически подчинённая главной части (главному предложению) и соединённая с ней союзом или союзным словом. П-ое предложение причины. Условное п-ое предложение. Придаточное, -ого; ср. Придаточное предложение. Определить п. Назвать п. В предложении два придаточных. Тип придаточного.

Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.

Answer (score 2):

В качестве **варианта:**

*Дополнить игру небольшим **фрагментом** с изменениями.*

Также: модулем, блоком, сегментом.

Comment: Спасибо, что представили один из вариантов этого предложения. То есть Вы согласны с тем, что использование слова "придаток" здесь неуместно?

Comment: Да, конечно. Это слово используется в терминологии  (медицина, лингвистика) и в данном тексте действительно выглядит неуместным.